# I want to create custom mini cart in magento2

Tags: magento2

**I want to create custom cart Like this**

[image]

And show my custom table products in this custom cart.

Answer (score 0):

You could check cart2quote module for reference - they added own minicart
https://www.cart2quote.com/

Then should have open source version available for download.

Comment: Yes i checked that module but its so complicated to understand code

Answer (score 0):

Below Code may be used as a reference for you to create custom mini cart.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="custom_minicart" as="custom_minicart" template="Vendor_Extension::custompopupcart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\custompopupcart.phtml

```
 <div style="display: none" id="popup-mpdal">
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.checkout = <?=  $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?=  $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                        $('#popup-mpdal').hide();
                    }
                }]
            };
            $('#popup-mpdal').show();
            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: okay let me check and let you know if any query Thanks. :)

Comment: after apply this code minicart open like popup i want disaply like minicart

Comment: try to add code in app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml and change block name from custom_minicart to minicart only

Comment: you can also refere this blog for customized minicart : https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/adding-a-new-field-to-the-minicart-in-magento-2-tutorial/